# Sorting json by numeric key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

My function:

```
sort: function (jsonData) {
    return jsonData.sort(function(a,b){
        return (a < b.id) ? -1:1;
    });
},
```

The error msg: `TypeError: jsonData.sort is not a function.`
JsonData example value:

```
Object{
131:Object
132:Object
136:Object
139:Object
142:Object
143:Object
144:Object
}
```

I need reverse sort of jsonData object.
This is not duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value). Because they are sorting by value, but i need sorting by key.

Comment: What is your input data ?

Comment: sort is works with Array not with Object

Comment: I now that sort doesn't work with object. I just show what i need. I need reverse sorting of object